"You're importing a component that needs next/headers. That only works in a Server Component which is not supported in the pages/ directory"-error
I'm following this tutorial to create a preview mode in Sanity. But when importing:
import { draftMode } from 'next/headers';

into client.ts I'm getting this error:

Error: × You're importing a component that needs next/headers.
That only works in a Server Component which is not supported in the
pages/ directory. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/
│ react-essentials#server-components

Which is super weird. Cus I'm using next version 14.1.0 and app router, don't even have a /pages directory. Have no idea how to continue to debug this, any ideas?

Having the exact same issue with the same tutorial, did you ever find a fix for it and get it to work?

After many hours of debugging, I found the solution.
The Problem:
You can't import server components into client components. This is what is causing that error.
The Solution:
If you import client from sanity/lib/client.ts into a file that uses useEffect (aka a client component), you will get that error.
Look for a useEffect and instead of importing the client, use the useClient hook like so:
const studioClient = useClient({ apiVersion: "2024-08-01" }).

More info on useClient in the v2 to v3 documentation
In my case, the problem was a custom input component called AsyncInput. I had made it by finding a solution in the sanity exchange that used Studio v2.
Hopefully this helps!
